# Dynamic angular models?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Okay, so I am building a fake dish builder for a restraunt. I have a form that includes everything you need to build it, and the only thing I am having trouble with is the ingredient list. Here is my HTML:

```
    <div class="icheckbox" ng-repeat="ing in ingredientList">
      {{ing}}
      <input type="checkbox" name="{{ing}}" ng-click="addIngredient(ing)"/>
      <input type="number" name="more" ng-model="ings.ing.more" placeholder="price for extra"/>
      <input type="number" name="less" ng-model="ings.ing.less" placeholder="price for less/none"/>
    </div>
```

and here is the (relevent) JS:

```
$scope.ings = {};    

$scope.ingredientList = ['lettuce', 'tomatoe', 'steak', 'pulled pork', 'green onion', 'red onion', 'mozarella', 'cheddar', 'bacon bits', 'chicken'];


$scope.addIngredient = function(which){
    $scope.ings[which] = which;
}
$scope.makeItem = function(item){
    item.ingredients = $scope.ings;
    console.log(item);
    ItemService.createItem(item)
      .then(handleRes, handleRes);
}
```

As I'm sure you guessed, when I am trying to check a box for a specific ingredient and add the price modifiers for more or less of that specific ingredient, it modifies the price for all ingredients in the list. E.g., I can't have individual modifiers because of the model. I know this is a problem with the model, but how can I rewrite my code to accomplish what I'm doing?

**for those reading this after the correct answer has been chosen, see the fiddle located here to see a more accurate HTML of what I was working with. By the way, the fiddle doesn't entirely work (for reasons I don't know, but I rarely use JSFiddle), but it is super easy to understand what I was trying to do if you see it I think. http://jsfiddle.net/Lrpjwyrg/13/**

Comment: Sorry, what exactly are you trying to do? Only show the more/less buttons if the check box is checked?

Comment: No. Let's say that my item is a pulled pork sand which. When that pulled pork box is checked, if I want extra pulled pork, then I need to charge them for that. I want to be able to set a price on extra pulled pork (or no pulled pork), and that to be contained in the ingredient object in the more or less field, respectively.

Comment: This specific code is on the fake restraunt owners side for making dishes to add to a menu, not the customer side.

Comment: @h3xc0ntr0l see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jigardafda/f1zh0Lqm/5/, do you want something like this?

Comment: @jad-panda not exactly that, but that's very close. It is quantity, but the number isn't a quantity modifier, it's a price modifier. I can refactor your code to work for me though (I think). Again, this is the side where I'm creating menu items, not ordering them.

Comment: what do you mean by modifier?

Comment: @h3xc0ntr0l see the answer i have added price.

Comment: methinks you need `ng-model="ings[ing].more"`

Comment: @Grundy - I got pretty excited, but I got this error.
    TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'more' of lettuce

Comment: @h3xc0ntr0l, i a bit change your fiddle and it seems work: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrpjwyrg/16/)

Comment: @Grundy - that you did. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i a bit change your fiddle:

first, use `ng-model="ings[ing].more"` and `ng-model="ings[ing].less"`.
second, save *object* in `ings` array instead of just *string*

```
$scope.addIngredient = function(which) {
  $scope.ings[which] = {
    name: which
  };
}
```

```js
angular.module('CpCtrl', []).controller('ControlPanelCtrl', [
  '$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.message = '';
    $scope.inglist = ['lettuce', 'tomatoe', 'steak', 'pulled pork', 'green onion', 'red onion', 'mozarella', 'cheddar', 'bacon bits', 'chicken'];
    $scope.sauceList = ['bbq', 'ranch', 'nacho cheese', 'yum sauce'];
    $scope.ings = {};

    $scope.addIngredient = function(which) {
      $scope.ings[which] = {
        name: which
      };
    }
    $scope.makeItem = function(item) {
      item.ingredients = $scope.ings;
      console.log(item);
    }

  }
]);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid text-center" ng-app="CpCtrl" ng-controller="ControlPanelCtrl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="page-title text-center">
      <h3> Welcome</h3> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h2> Make Item </h2>
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="itemname">Item Name</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="item.itemname" id="itemname" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="itemdescription">Item Description</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" ng-model="item.itemdescription" id="itemdescription"></textarea>
        </div>


        <!-- pizza, sub or spud -->
        <label>
          <div class="icheckbox_square-green">
            <input type="checkbox" name="pizza" ng-model="item.pizza" ng-click="setBase()" />Pizza
          </div>
        </label>
        <label>
          <div class="icheckbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="sub" ng-model="item.sub" ng-click="setBase()" />Sub
          </div>
        </label>
        <label>
          <div class="icheckbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="spud" ng-model="item.spud" ng-click="setBase()" />Spud
          </div>
        </label>
        <!-- end -->

        <!-- prices -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="spud-price" ng-if="item.spud">Spud Price</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="number" name="spud-price" ng-if="item.spud" id="spud-price" ng-model="item.price.spud" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="pizza-price" ng-if="item.pizza">Pizza Price</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="number" name="pizza-price" ng-if="item.pizza" ng-model="item.price.pizza" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="sub-price" ng-if="item.sub">Sub Price</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="number" name="sub-price" ng-if="item.sub" ng-model="item.price.sub" />
        </div>

        <!-- end -->

        <!-- ingredients -->
        <div ng-repeat="ing in inglist">
          {{ing}}
          <input type="checkbox" name="{{ing}}" ng-click="addIngredient(ing)" />
          <input type="number" name="more" ng-model="ings[ing].more" placeholder="price for extra" />
          <input type="number" name="less" ng-model="ings[ing].less" placeholder="price for less/none" />
        </div>
        <!-- end -->

        <!-- picture -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="picture">Add Picture(s)</label>
          <input type="file" name="picture" />
        </div>

        <!-- end -->

        <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="makeItem(item)">Create</a>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end item creation -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the right answer. But i think it is close to what you want.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('cntrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.ingredientList = [{
        name: 'lettuce',
        count: 0,
        price: 23,
        selected: false
    }, {
        name: 'tomatoe',
        count: 0,
        price: 87,
        selected: false
    }, {
        name: 'steak',
        count: 0,
        price: 98,
        selected: false
    }, {
        name: 'pulled pork',
        count: 0,
        price: 292,
        selected: false
    }];

    $scope.setItOne = function (idx) {
        if ($scope.ingredientList[idx].count < 1) {
            $scope.ingredientList[idx].count = 1;
        }
        updateSelectedingredients();
    };

    function updateSelectedingredients() {
        $scope.selectedingredients = $scope.ingredientList.filter(function (item) {
            return item.selected;
        });
    }
        
        $scope.getTotal = function(){
            var total = 0;
            ( $scope.selectedingredients || []).forEach(function(item){
                total = total + item.count * item.price;
            });
            return total;
        };

    $scope.makeItem = function () {
        alert(JSON.stringify($scope.selectedingredients));
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="cntrl">
        <div class="icheckbox" ng-repeat="ing in ingredientList">{{ing.name}}
            <input type="checkbox" name="{{ing}}" ng-model="ing.selected" ng-change="setItOne($index)" />
            <button ng-click="ing.count = ing.count + 1">Up</button>
            <button ng-click="ing.count = ing.count - 1" ng-disabled="ing.count < 1">Down</button>
             | {{ing.count}} x {{ing.price | currency}} = {{ing.count * ing.price | currency}}
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <div>Selected items
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in selectedingredients">{{item.name }} x {{item.count}} -> {{item.count}} x {{item.price | currency}} = {{item.count * item.price| currency}}</li>
            </ul>
            <b>Total: {{ getTotal() | currency}}</b>
        </div>
        <button ng-click="makeItem()">Make Item</button>
    </div>
</div>
```